# Django return objects to HTML from view with queryset?

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I trying to show some info in HTML from query set in Django. But I don't know the best way to do it.

The idea is when I open the page this show me the name of user and the competitions related with it. The user can create competition in admin of Django.

My url is that.

```
url(r'^home/(?P<company_name>\w+)', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

The model.

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    startingDate = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
```

In views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = User, Competition
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'company'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        company = self.kwargs['company_name']
        try:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(username__exact=company).get()
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            queryset = None
        return queryset
```

The code above return me the User, when I write in url something like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/diego/

The HTML home show me the name of User for example:

```
{% if company %} <div class="jumbotron"> <div class="container">
    {{company.username}}  </div></div> {% endif %}
```

But, I need to show the competitions created by the User with a 'for' in HTML.

I tried with chains return the two query set but I don't work it.

Also this.

```
queryset2 = Competition.objects.filter(user__username__exact=company).get()
```

The get() show me the error that return more one object. That is logic because the user has 3 competitions related with this.

Some little example for that? or any idea for resolve my question.

Thanks a lot

I Tried this, but the 'User' object is not iterable (Obviously it is just one)

```
class HomeView(ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'home.html'
context_object_name = 'company'

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    company = self.kwargs['company_name']

    try:
        queryset = User.objects.filter(username__exact=company).get()
        queryset2 = Competition.objects.filter(user__username__exact=company)
        result_list = list(chain(queryset, queryset2))
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        result_list = None
    return result_list
```

I have been trying and trying and delete the get() for first query set and the data return to HTML.

How can I access to the fields of the list in HTML but with the class, If I print the variable 'company' the result is that.

```
[<User: diego>, <Competition: test1>, <Competition: test2>]
```

But with 'for' just I obtain the string values. How can I difference the 'User' and 'Competition'

```
 {%for compa in company%} 
   {{compa}} 
 {%endfor%}
```

the result is:
diego
test1
test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont have to return the different querysets from get_queryset, Its complicated. List view has one method called get_context_data"
you can override it to fill the extra objects or data you want.

for example just write

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = User, Competition
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'company'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        company = self.kwargs['company_name']
        try:
            queryset =    User.objects.filter(username__exact=company).get()
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            queryset = None
            return queryset
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset2 = Competition.objects.filter(user__username__exact=company)
        context['competitions'] = queryset2
        return context
```

Here you will be getting company and "competitions" separately. Use them well in templates. just try it. It should work